# Known classic problem or not?

Tags: problem-solving, set-partition

There is a set of positive whole numbers without null. I have to find the minimal number of subsets of the original set so, that the the sum of two numbers in a subset can't be the value of a number in the same subset.
Is there any known problem for this task? (I mean a problem like Partition problem, Subset sum problem etc..)

I'm looking for this on the internet a long time ago. I have not found it yet.

Comment: Schur's theorem is vaguely related.